# CSS broken on days I was online

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Please check the image, on my profile the CSS in the datepicker is gone - I'm using the latest version of Chrome.

[image: This picture is from Google Chrome]

Comment: Humm. No repro for me. Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: I see the same effect for a moment before the javascript(?) loads the full view. Are you blocking anything or using extensions that affect the site?

Comment: Do you happen to be zoomed in/out? What happens when you `Ctrl + 0`?

Answer (score 1):

This problem resolved itself. After using inPrivate I didn't see it either so something must have been wrong somehow.

Norepro, and self-fixed.